# Singapore Airlines online check-in and document/credit card/visa verification

Tags: tickets, check-in, singapore-airlines

In their website, Singapore Airlines write about online check-in (at https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/au/travel-info/check-in/online-mobile-checkin/). It is mentioned:

> At the airport, proceed directly to the Immigration counter if you don’t have bags to check in and if you don’t require travel document/visa/credit card verification at the check-in counter.

It is sometimes quite important to know whether you have to go to the check-in counter because if you arrived from another flight that is on a separate ticket, this would mean you have to go through immigration and then go back airside (rather than just staying airside the whole time).

Does anyone know in what cases such "travel document/visa/credit card verification" is required?

Also, I assume if it is required when are you notified of this, in advance (via e-mail e.g.) or when you do online check-in?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to go through immigration if you are on two separate tickets: it depends on the airlines.

Comment: If you don't have bags to check back in, I believe whatever you would have to do at a check-in counter should be doable at a transfer desk, or at the gate, though I have never quite been in that situation. You would indeed be notified at time of online check-in, as you would not receive a valid boarding pass.

Comment: If you are already passed immigration, can you not do the document verification with the agent at the gate?

Answer (score 2):

During airlines check in, including Singapore, at a computerised active [kiosk](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/travel-info/check-in/kiosk-checkin/) or staffed desk, you are asked to scan or present a valid [travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_document), e.g., passport, any visa(s) required for entry to destination(s), and, in some cases, reservation detail (scan or enter barcode, e-ticket or booking reference number).

Some airlines may ask to see the credit card with which tickets were purchased, to avert fraudulent or unauthorised use. Failure to do so can result in a refusal to board you.